# Request.QueryString - replacing + (plus) sign with space

Tags: asp.net, query-string

> abcd.aspx?ST=f7aABcBdHIm7E8/0SAWKGtz8qKkhwNpJuZ+Jh+Jg+jg=&ET=d0698IjyKXsfkDDAmgy79kOd8+ONzX6IlgSrDME0QHw=

when I use the below code in my .cs page:

```
Request.QueryString["ST"]
```

It returns the value:

```
"f7aABcBdHIm7E8/0SAWKGtz8qKkhwNpJuZ Jh Jg jg="
```

It replaced the + sign with a space character (" ").

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Try the above link http://forums.asp.net/t/1331660.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`+` sign has a semantic meaning in the query string. It is used to represent a space.

```
Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ST"])
```

You can use `Server.UrlEncode`. Spaces ( ) are converted to plus signs (+).

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

why not try this

in source link user following line

```
 Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?ST="+ Server.UrlEncode(Server.HtmlEncode( "abc+xyz+lmn")));
```

and in destination page user following line

```
Server.HtmlDecode( Request.QueryString["ST"]);
```

this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I tested it. It gives the right result

```
string cidEncode = Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["CID"]);
string cid = Regex.Replace(cidEncode, "%3d", "=", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```