# Why does postman substitute characters in my get request string?

Tags: c#, api, url, postman, endpoint

I am making a get request through postman and when the request reaches my controller, the characters like "+" are converted to empty spaces " ". The api is written in c#.

My controller code is:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("")]
public partial class _DesifrarCusController : CaramlController, I_DesifrarCusController 
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("descifrarCus")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetDescifrarCusResponse( [FromUri] string cus = null ) {
        return Ok (ExecGetDescifrarCusResponse(cus));
        //return Ok();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what postman is doing with the request string?

I have tried to send the string between quotes and with ascii characters and still the problem persists.

[I add capture of the postman headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFaLC.jpg)

Comment: Postman is not converting "+" to spaces.

Comment: If not, why does the string get to the controller wrong?

Comment: @pepaSoftware can you share the Headers screenshot of Postman?

Comment: Look through search results - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20asp.net%20plus%20replaced%20with%20%20space... I don't have good answer handy - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143193/request-querystring-replacing-plus-sign-with-space is the first result, there is probably one better explaining that and including .Net core too... But + is space...

Comment: @vivek nuna i will edit the question to add image of postman config

Comment: @pepaSoftware I asked to Headers screenshot not Params

Comment: @vivek nuna sorry, image updated

Comment: @pepaSoftware try `cus = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(cus);` before line `return Ok (ExecGetDescifrarCusResponse(cus));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the parameter on Postman. First add the parameter under `Params` tab

[image]

then select the value and right click the value chose `EncodeURIComponent`
[image]

then you will get encoded parameter

[image]

Reference: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/

Answer (score 0):

Postman send data from query by encoding it with urlencode.This is normal. Sending this kind of long data from url is not best practise.I recommend use HttpPost and send data from body.

Answer (score 0):

Data in URIs need to be [UrlEncoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). When your C# application recevies the data it will decode it which will replace the plus signs with spaces (which to be fair is the older standard).

Postman won't do this automaticly for you, but it can help.

If you have a value like this.

[image: Picture of a non encoded url in postman]

You can select the text and right click it to get the option to encode the value.

[image: Picture of the context menu in Postman to encode values]

This will encode the value properly and it will be received in your C# application as expected.

[image: Picture of an encoded url in postman]

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned in other answers, it's encoding issue.
Alternatively you could use [[FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) and then just put your string in body request part of postman

```
public IHttpActionResult GetDescifrarCusResponse( [FromBody] string cus = null ) {
        return Ok (ExecGetDescifrarCusResponse(cus));
        //return Ok();
    }
```